# Jsoup prasring heading h2

Tags: java, html, parsing, dom, jsoup

Hello everyone i am trying to parse heading text from this website http://feed43.com/alytus_06.xml.

html code:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body onload="doLoad()">
    <div class="body feed-preview">
        <table class="main" style="margin-top:10px">...</table>
        <div class ="main">
            <h1>ALYTUS_06</h1>
            <p>ALYTUS_06</p>
            <p>...</p>
            <p class="date-preview" style="margin-bottom:0px;">Last Updated: Mon, 24 Feb 2014 10:01:54 GMT</p>
        </div>
        <div class ="main">
            <h2>
                <span class="bullet">&nbsp;</span>
                "-1"
            </h2>
        <div class="p" id="item_1">...</div>
        <h2>..</h2>
        <div class="p" id="item_2">...</div>
        </div>
        <div class="main footer">       
              Feed43 v. 1.3. Copyright © 2006–2011 A.I.Studio. All rights reserved.
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

```
    public static void main( String[] args ) throws IOException
{
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse("UTF-8", "http://feed43.com/alytus_06.xml");
        for (Element e : doc.select("h2")) {
            System.out.println(e.text());
        }
}
```

i cant extract that temperature "-1" from div.class main in h2 from this code, maybe someone could help me?

Comment: What does your program print out?

Answer (score 1):

To get the first element change your code like this

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://feed43.com/alytus_06.xml").get();
Element ele=doc.select("item title").first();
System.out.println(ele.text());
```

To get all element with title tag within item

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://feed43.com/alytus_06.xml").get();
Elements ele=doc.select("item title");
for(Element element:ele)
{
   System.out.println(element.text());
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to get all elements not the first one? Thank You.

Comment: can you specify the data you need?